# How to start an animation at the beginning of a longpress gesture?

Tags: swiftui

Title says it all :)

I have a `dragGesture` within a `scrollview`. I was able to manage that by combining a `longpressGesture` before drag so the button is not activated accidentally when the user scrolls. But I'd like to add some visal clue after the longpress has started to let the user know that this thing is active if you longpress.

Here is my code, it's pretty standard. I was unable to find the start event of a longpress.

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color .white)
.onTapGesture {}
.gesture(
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: self.minimuDuration, maximumDistance: 0)
        .updating(self.$isLongPressed) { value, state, transcation in
                state = value
        }.sequenced(before:
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onEnded({ (value) in })
            .onChanged { value in }
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as long-press gesture detected you `self.$isLongPressed` will be triggered, so this is your flag for visual feedback animation. For example:

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color.white.opacity(self.isLongPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
.animation(.default)
.onTapGesture {}
.gesture(
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: self.minimuDuration, maximumDistance: 0)
        .updating(self.$isLongPressed) { value, state, transcation in
    ...
```

Comment: Bro! Is there a question I ask you wont answer ? lol :) thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't help me but this is the correct answer, so I mark it ok. The fact that my longpress is under a scrollview kinda messes with the animation.